# simple SQL Pivot Query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I apologize for my ignorance. I just am not familiar with pivot queries AT ALL and all the examples I find seem about as clear as mud. I have table that returns GroupName and ID Numbers.

For Example:

```
SELECT GroupName, IDnumber FROM do.Table_1
```

Returns

```
GroupName                IDnumber
1                          8395
1                          A660
1                          8396
1                          A661
2                          8398
2                          A662
2                          8399
```

What I want is something more like this:

```
GroupName              ID1     ID2   ID3   ID4
1                      8395   A660  8396   A661
2                      8398   A662  8399   NULL
```

How can I do this? Pivot query? Some other method?

I am open to suggestion and appreciate any help you could provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using `PIVOT` but not in this shape, you have firstly to generate a row number to use it to format the data in the way you want. Something like this:

```
WITH Ranked
AS
(
  SELECT GroupName, IDnumber, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY GroupName) AS RN
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT GroupName,
  [1] AS ID1, [2] AS ID2, [3] AS ID3, [4] AS ID4
FROM Ranked AS r
PIVOT
(
  MAX(IDnumber)
  FOR RN IN([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS p;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e713/6)

This will give you:

```
| GROUPNAME |  ID1 |  ID2 |  ID3 |    ID4 |
|-----------|------|------|------|--------|
|         1 | 8395 | A660 | 8396 |   A661 |
|         2 | 8398 | A662 | 8399 | (null) |
```

---

If you want to do it dynamically and not to write the row number by hand in the `pivot` table operator, you have to do it using dynamic SQL, something like:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colnames AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(RN)
                       FROM 
               (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY GroupName) AS RN
                 FROM Table1 
               ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @colnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(RN) + 'AS' +   
                        QUOTENAME('ID' + CAST(RN AS NVARCHAR(5)))
                       FROM 
               (
                 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY GroupName) AS RN
                 FROM Table1 
               ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'WITH Ranked
                  AS
                  (
                    SELECT GroupName, IDnumber, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY GroupName) AS RN
                    FROM Table1
                  )
                  SELECT GroupName, ' + @colnames +
                  ' FROM Ranked AS r
                  PIVOT
                  (
                    MAX(IDnumber)
                    FOR RN IN(' + @cols + ')' +
                  ') p';

execute(@query);
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e713/15)

This should give you the same result:

```
| GROUPNAME |  ID1 |  ID2 |  ID3 |    ID4 |
|-----------|------|------|------|--------|
|         1 | 8395 | A660 | 8396 |   A661 |
|         2 | 8398 | A662 | 8399 | (null) |
```

Comment: Ok, This works fantastic! It does exactly what I want to do. But I can't save it. When I try to save the non-dynamic version as a view so I can reuse it for my application, it cuts the first three lines off. Can't figure out why. If I try to save the dynamic version it says it has a problem with the DECLARE statement and won't let me save it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jeff - You can't use it in a view. You can do it in a stored procedure instead. It should work fine.

Comment: Ok, I got it figured out and working in my application. Thank you!

Comment: I even went this one better and figured out how to do it with a parameter passed to it from a query string! It's working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use dynamic pivoting since the Id will be dynamic. Here is your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM 
(
SELECT 1 GroupName,                '8395' IDnumber
  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,                          'A660'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,                          '8396'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 1,                          'A661'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,                          '8398'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,                          'A662'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,                          '8399'
)TAB
```

Select row number over each Groupname and insert into a temporary table so that it can be used for both selecting the columns for pivoting and inside the pivot

```
SELECT *,
'ID' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY GROUPNAME) AS VARCHAR(10)) IDS
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM #TEMP
```

Select columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + IDS + ']', 
           '[' + IDS + ']')
           FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT IDS FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
           ORDER BY IDS
```

Now pivot dynamically

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT * FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MAX(IDnumber)
                 FOR IDS IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p      

            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

[Click here to view the result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8a494/1)  (incase an error is occured on loading page press RUNSQL, it works)

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: I have updated. Please check. Its simple to read and understand @Jeff